# React Native AsyncStorage not getting data

Tags: android, react-native, asyncstorage

I am using following code for storing and retrieving data. But it isn't working as I want.

**Setting data:**

```
async setDataFromApi(token, json) {
const {goBack} = this.props.navigation; // Navigation
let iext_inf = {
  token: token,
  userid: json.data.id,
  username: json.data.username,
  image: json.data.profile_picture,
};
console.log(iext_inf);
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('iext_inf', JSON.stringify(iext_inf) ); // Stuck here
  goBack();
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error");
}
}
```

**Getting data:**

```
async componentWillMount() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("iext_inf"); //Stuck here
console.log(value);

  if (value !== null){
    this.setState({
      data : value
    })
  }

  if ( this.state.data !== null ) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {'access_token': value});
  }

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried adding single data and retrieving it and it worked for some reason. Now it's not.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: is the data that you are passing to the asyncstorage valid? are you getting any error

Comment: @PanagiotisVrs I think its valid. Not getting any error.

Comment: can you try callbacks like AsyncStorage.getItem('iext_inf', (err, result) => { })

Comment: @PanagiotisVrs Tried it already. Not getting any error or result!

Comment: can i suggest try a static object like the example of react native ? let UID123_object = {
 name: 'Chris',
 age: 30,
 traits: {hair: 'brown', eyes: 'brown'},
};

Comment: also which version are you using?

Comment: It didn't work.
Version:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.50.3

Comment: Did you solve this? Try removing `async await` and using `AsyncStorage.getItem().then(value=>{})`?

Answer (score 1):

> `AsyncStorage` only takes string as a value and key.

You are passing an object try to set string not an object. I am not sure `JSON.stringfy()` works for `AsyncStorage`.

Comment: this is not valid. JSON.stringify turns the object to a string. There is no reason why this is not working for the AsyncStorage

Comment: The value that I was passing was `null` which caused AsyncStorage to stuck without throwing any errors.