# react native AsyncStorage not working?

Tags: react-native

for setting the item i am using this first code.

```
           console.log(ACCESS_TOKEN);

                     console.log(typeof(ACCESS_TOKEN));

                     async function setToken() {

                     try {
                        await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', ACCESS_TOKEN);
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log("token not set")
                        }
                     }
                     setToken();
```

for getting the item , i am using this code

```
componentWillMount(){


async function getToken() {
  try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
      if (value !== null){
        console.log(value);

        this.setState({ access_token: value });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log( "Error retrieving data")
    }
  }

  getToken();
```

the result i am getting in first code is

1a61b72b-ee83-43de-9cf9-3fa270ce694d

string

but getting nothing at console at getting code . why ?

Comment: can u show some more your code? not getting a clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this one:**

**set item using this**

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

**get item using this**

```
 try {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token')
            .then((value) => {
                if (value) {
                   // you will get your access_token here
                }
            }).done();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error); // you will get error here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the item

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', ACCESS_TOKEN)
    .then(() => {  
       //your success code   
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      //your failure code
    })
```

To get the item

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token')
  .then(access_token=> {
    //you will be getting the access token here
  })
  .catch(err => {
    //handle the error
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you intended:

```
async function getToken() {

    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
      if (value !== null){
        console.log(value);

        this.setState({ access_token: value });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log( "Error retrieving data")
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    getToken();
}
```

If instead your code is getting stuck while working with AsyncStorage, there's a  well known bug reproducible only in development: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12830

They only way to bypass it, afaik, it is just to restart the debugger when you get stuck

Remember that setting state during componentWillMount is not the correct way to do it. You should use the constuctor for that

Answer (score 0):

My answer might not directly apply to your case, But I had the same problem as you did with `AsyncStorage` and It was getting stuck, so this might help other people.
As stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690402/react-native-asyncstorage-not-getting-data?rq=1#answer-47692711):

> AsyncStorage only takes string as a value and key.

But I was accidentally giving it `null` (which as you know is considered an object) so it got stuck. So check if you are passing a string value as both the first and second argument to setItem.